# How to extract lat long value out of XY mouse value in Deck.gl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, deck.gl

Does Deck.gl have any built-in function that calculates the lat long value that mouse cursor is pointing at?

I am trying to build interaction which puts the selected area in the center using `setState()`

I have a constant `initialViewState` contains the long and lat value which is assigned to `viewState`

```
const initialViewState = {
  longitude: -79.3832,
  latitude: 43.6532,
  (...)
};

const [viewState, setViewState] = useState(initialViewState);
```

Then from `onClick`, I pass props that contains `x` and `y` value of the mouse cursor.

```
const layer = new GeoJsonLayer({
        id: 'geojson-layer',
        data: geoData,
        (...)
        onClick: props => viewUpdate(props)      
      });
```

And I'd like to update lat long value of `viewState` through `viewUpdate()` but I am not sure how I can convert x,y to corresponding lat long value on the map.

```
const viewUpdate = ({x, y}) => {
   //convert x,y value to lat long value then update the viewState
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can use `coordinate` property that returns lat long value instead of  `x` and `y`.

Comment: `coordinate` which is returned by pickObject, that can't be correct in context of actual lat&lng